# How to pass variables to aggregate(match) with Mongoose and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this kind of document:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "time": {
         "start": ISODate("2016-01-18T00:12:41.000Z"),
         "end": ISODate("2016-01-18T05:12:41.000Z")
    },
    "subject":"javascript",
    "class": "ABC"
}
...
```

I have client/server app, client will send request to server with four variables: `timeS`, `timeE`, `sub`, `class`. They may be empty strings.

In my server, how can I write an aggregate query to find records matching filter conditions? I want to ignore search terms that are empty.

```
var query = db.collection.aggregate([
                        {"$match": {"$and":[]}}                                                     
                        ]);
```

example:

If `timeS` is not empty, I want `$match` with `$eq`.

If `timeS` and `timeE` both are not empty, I want `$match` with `$gte:timeS, $lte:timeE`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the match criteria dynamically based on presence of input variable.

```
var matchCriteria = {}, pipeline;

var timeS, timeE, sub, clazz; //initialize them from your input

if (timeS) {
 matchCriteria['time.start'] = timeS;  
}
if (timeE) {
  matchCriteria['time.end'] = timeE;
}
if (sub) {
  matchCriteria.subject = sub;
}

if (clazz) {
  matchCriteria.class = clazz;
}

pipeline = [
  {
    $match: matchCriteria
  }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

You may have to do other checks like atleast one variable is present to make sure  match critieria is not empty.

Comment: thank for your help, but in case, I want match $gte:start, $lte:end, so how can i do?

Comment: @user1697646  matchCriteria.start = {$gte: timeS},  matchCriteria.end = {$lte: timeE}

Comment: it's not work, bro. I use mongoose and nodejs, maybe syntax incorrect.

Comment: If my collection have kind of document: "time" : {"start": ISODate("2016-01-18T00:12:41.000Z"),
    "end": ISODate("2016-01-18T05:12:41.000Z")}
so What matchCriteria format?

Comment: @user1697646 use dot notation 'time.start',  'time.end', I have updated answer.

Comment: how i find record with time.start in [time1, time2]? because of if i set matchCriteria['time.start'] =  {$gte: time1} and matchCriteria['time.start'] =  {$lte: time2} so final value is matchCriteria['time.start'] =  {$gte: time2}. I have to create another matchCriteria?